Is there a way to retrieve the name and subtitle of older versions of an iOS app using the App Store Connect REST API?
I have several iOS apps published on App Store Connect, each with multiple versions. I want to fetch and display the version-specific titles and subtitles for these apps. The App Store Connect REST API provides the app/{id}/appInfos endpoint, which returns information about the current live version or the upcoming version that will go live(only 2 entries). Is there another method to retrieve and display the titles and subtitles for specific versions of the apps?
